# Drupal website migration from Prod env to Dev env

Tags: drupal, migration

there seems to be a small issue I am experiencing. I am trying to migrate a drupal website existing on a production environment onto my development environment.

I did an sql dump of the databases on the prod environment, and installed the same version of Drupal on my local, changed the base url, and took note of the database it was connected to. However, while running the install.php, I mention the exact same db and the credentials.

Drupal is unable to recognize this database. Also, isn't setting up a new Drupal installation going to overwrite the existing database which is the scenario given that I am downloading an existing website and setting it up locally.

Anyone have any leads on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install Drupal in the development environment, which will let it correctly configure the values in the config file. Then drop all tables in the development database while keeping the database itself intact, including its permissions. Import the database contents of the production environment into the development database.

Comment: by dumping that database u mean I delete it and simply import the production environment database which basically has the same name as the one on the dev environment. Essentially, fooling Drupal :p ?

Comment: I mean at the development end, drop all the tables of the database while keeping the database itself, with its permissions and so on, intact. Then, import the database contents that you exported from the production environment. You can think of this as 'fooling' Drupal if you like, but this is a perfectly normal process. When you install Drupal, it does create a database but the primary local configuration is stored in the configuration file. Importing a different Drupal database just imports its site configuration and content, and doesn't have any bearing on the server configuration.

Comment: Answer expanded to clarify the above.